# How to disable "CORS" in CN1-Web-Component?

Tags: codenameone

our customer points out that Webcomponet, present in codename one visual lib, allows Cross-Origin Resource attacks in JS loaded inside it.
Actually, the pages we load into the CodeNameOne-Web-Component have some Java script we wrote. But this JavaScript code doesn't have any external call via ajax or any other mechanism to make external requests. Our JS code only communicates with our CN1-Java-Code, using techniques provided by CN1. Only our java code executes external calls.

That said, **Is there some way to disable CORS at the CN1-web-component level?** Maybe a Compilation-hint or even a flag that can be set into the WebComponet. So, we could disable CORS and analyze the app behavior.

Comment: Do you mean load by invoking setHTML or setURL? JavaScript you inject into the component is essentially an attack but since your app has control of the code it can decide not to do so. I don't follow what you're looking for, a way to disable the methods of browser component?

For proper cors to work your website itself needs to define an HTTP header. We can't control that on the client side.